# How to implement a UA Server using Milo without any security/certificates?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I am trying to create a demo server using Milo SDK. I have looked at the ExampleServer.java but really confused what's going on with the certificates and security. I am unsure of what KeyStoreLoader and all the other aspects. I just want to create a demo server at the bare minimum with default everything and no security. How would I go about this?